# Разбить самопересекающийся многоугольник на части без самопересечений, зная все точки пересечений

Tags: алгоритм, графика, геометрия

Есть задача:  разбить самопересекающийся многоугольник на части без самопересечений. Проблему нахождения всех точек пересечения я решил: полным перебором. Знаю, что есть алгоритм Бентли-Оттмана, но мне легче было написать полный перебор, так как не нашел хорошего полноценного описания алгоритма на русском языке.

Вопрос сейчас такой: что мне дальше делать с этими точками? Есть ли какой-то способ, зная эти точки, разбить теперь мой многоугольник? Знаю про [способ](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html) (по этой ссылке в заголовке "Decompose into Simple Pieces"), при котором это делается с каждым шагом алгоритма Бентли-Оттмана, есть ли какой-то способ сделать аналогично в моем случае? Или все-таки придется разбираться с алгоритмом Бентли-Оттмана? Если да, то, возможно, у кого-то есть хорошее понятное полноценное описание этого алгоритма на русском языке?

Comment: Вы могли бы проиллюстрировать свой вопрос? Т.е. о каких конкретно многоугольниках и самопересечениях идет речь. Также, решение нужно общее, или ваше условие несколько "стандартизировано" и допускает некоторые упрощения/допущения?

Comment: Иллюстрации есть по ссылке, решение нужно общее

Answer (score 2):

Если задача не состоит в том, чтобы всё сделать самостоятельно, посмотрите, что умеет Clipper (Delphi, C++, C# и некоторые другие языки). Работа этой библиотеки основана на алгоритме Vatti.

Функция [SimplifyPolygon](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Functions/SimplifyPolygon.htm), похоже, делает то, что Вам требуется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы делать все самостоятельно как раз

Comment: Библиотека в исходниках, можно подсмотреть, как это делается.